# JQuery hover change border and mouse leave problem

Tags: jquery

Example: https://codepen.io/ricardo-sud/pen/gOPMBRN

```js
    $("*").hover(
      function () {
      
        $(this).addClass("result_hover");
      },
      function () {
        $(this).removeClass("result_hover");
      }
    );
```

```css
     .result {
        height: 72px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #000;
      }
      .result_hover {
        border: 5px solid red;
      }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="result">
      <div class="item">
        <div id="item1">
          <i class="icon"></i>&nbsp;##
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <p>
    Testing
    </p>
    <p>
    Testing 1
    </p>
```

I'm trying to add a border (I prefer to do it inline if possible) to any element that has the mouseover (not the parents), but this propagates and the red border not are only over one element but over parents or other elements. Follow the link and see the problem.

Any help are welcome

Best Regards

Comment: I have NO control over the webpage content and cant change the CSS.n This must be pure Jquaery, thats why i mention that will be better to do it inline.

Comment: in which element you wanted to show border on mousehover event? in your code you have provided in all elements.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code.

Is this what you want?

```js
$(".result").hover(
      function () {
      
        $(this).addClass("result_hover");
      },
      function () {
        $(this).removeClass("result_hover");
      }
    );
```

```css
.result {
        height: 72px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #000;
      }
      .result_hover {
        border: 5px solid red;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="result">
      <div class="item">
        <div id="item1">
          <i class="icon"></i>&nbsp;##
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <p>
    Testing
    </p>
    <p>
    Testing 1
    </p>
```

Comment: I want to be able to select ANY element. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need other triggers and `e.stopPropagation()`:

```js
$("*").mouseover(function(e) {
  $(this).addClass("result_hover")
  e.stopPropagation()
})

$("*").mouseout(function(e) {
  $(this).removeClass("result_hover")
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```

```css
.result {
  height: 72px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.result_hover {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result">
  <div class="item">
    <div id="item1">
      <i class="icon"></i>&nbsp;##
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<p>
  Testing
</p>
<p>
  Testing 1
</p>
```

### EDIT

I would also not use `border`, because the content just jumps around. Use `outline` instead:

```js
$("*").mouseover(function(e) {
  $(this).addClass("result_hover")
  e.stopPropagation()
})

$("*").mouseout(function(e) {
  $(this).removeClass("result_hover")
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```

```css
.result {
  height: 72px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.result_hover {
  outline: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result">
  <div class="item">
    <div id="item1">
      <i class="icon"></i>&nbsp;##
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<p>
  Testing
</p>
<p>
  Testing 1
</p>
```

Comment: Great!! If i want to add a background-color to the selection, what i need to do? I just manually add yellow as background-color to the .result_hover class but everything goes yellow!!! Your answer is the correct one, how do i pick it?

Comment: @RicardoSud you can add the background to the `result_hover` class - everything goes yellow, because `*` selects `html`, `body` - everything. If you hover over an other element, only that element's background will be colored. As for selecting this answer as the accepted answer: I think you need a higher **SO** score to accept an answer, but you can upvote. Anyways, I'm happy that I could help.